# Problems executing serial sequence of Animation Sets to reverse an animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview

I'd like to create an animation for an *ImageView* that rotates the image while scaling from 100% to 0% and fading from opaque to transparent (**SET 1**) and then reverses the animation (**SET 2**). The two animation sets work if taken one by one, but if I put them together I can't see anything, because the start values of animation set 2 are applied immediately, even if the startOffset of its children is set to start after animation set 1 has been completed. I think I've understood that *fadeAfter* and *fadeBefore* should be used to avoid applying start values of animation set 2 before it starts, but it didn't work for me. I've tried also *fadeAfter* to true in SET 1, removing SET 2, to see if it works, i.e. if the transformation of SET 1 is persisted after the end, but again it didn't work.. So, is it possible to produce the result I want with the following animation, maybe using *fadeAfter*, *fadeBefore* and *fillEnabled* attributes? Should it work with an *ImageView* view?

**ANIMATION XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <!-- SET 1 -->
    <set
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:shareInterpolator="true" >
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:startOffset="500"/>
        <rotate
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="500"
            android:toDegrees="720" />

        <scale
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromXScale="100%"
            android:fromYScale="100%"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="500"
            android:toXScale="0%"
            android:toYScale="0%" />
    </set>

    <!-- SET 2 -->
    <set
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:shareInterpolator="true">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
            android:toAlpha="1"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:startOffset="1500"/>
        <rotate
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="720"
        android:startOffset="1500" />

        <scale
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromXScale="0%"
            android:fromYScale="0%"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toXScale="100%"
            android:toYScale="100%"
        android:startOffset="1500" />
    </set>
</set>
```

**ANIMATION START IN JAVA CODE**

```java
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.test_animation);
iv.startAnimation(animation);
```

**TEST WITH ANIMATION REPEAT**

I've tried also to remove SET 2 and add the following code before *startAnimation*, but the animation is not repeated in the reversed order (I can specify also RESTART and X repeat cycles and it doesn't work). Any idea or suggestion?!

```java
animation.setRepeatCount(1);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Comment: I've seen that if I specify only the *scale* transformation and I set *fromXScale* and *fromYscale* to 100% and *toXScale* and *toYScale* to 1% in SET 1 and then in SET 2 I set *fromXScale* and *fromYScale* to 100% and *toXScale* and *toYScale* to 10000% in SET 2 everything works... so the 100% in SET 2 means 100% of the dimension found at the end of SET 1 (even if I've set *fillAfter* for false in SET 1), and so the 10000% at the end of SET 2 mans 100% of the original size (10000% of 1% = 100%)... I think I'm missing something in all this stuff..